# Running a C code with Open SSL

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl

I am not able to compile the following code. I run it in a MACOSX with the following command in the terminal:
$gcc filename.c -lssl

I understand that MACOS already has an inbuilt openssl (which i can call as a command in the terminal). But I am not sure if i am linking it to the library in the correct fashion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
EVP_MD_CTX mdctx;
const EVP_MD *md;
char mess1[] = "Test Message\n";
char mess2[] = "Hello World\n";
unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
int md_len, i;

OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

if(!argv[1]) {
    printf("Usage: mdtest digestname\n");
    exit(1);
}

md = EVP_get_digestbyname(argv[1]);

if(!md) {
    printf("Unknown message digest %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}

EVP_MD_CTX_init(&mdctx);
EVP_DigestInit_ex(&mdctx, md, NULL);
EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, mess1, strlen(mess1));
EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, mess2, strlen(mess2));
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&mdctx);

printf("Digest is: ");
for(i = 0; i < md_len; i++) printf("%02x", md_value[i]);
printf("\n");
}
```

My error is:
 Undefined symbols:
  "_EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup", referenced from: _main in ccfZG7WJ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am surprised by the error since it shows "Undefined Symbols" instead of "Header file not found". Can you please help me debug this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSSL has 2 libraries:  `libssl` and `libcrypto`.  Include libcrypto, too.

```
gcc filename.c -lssl -lcrypto
```

(You actually don't need `-lssl` at all for this program, but it doesn't hurt to include it)

[libssl](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html) is for making actual SSL or TLS connections, like when connecting to a web server with https.  It also exports `SSL_load_error_strings`, which is useful even when working only with the cryptography library.

[libcrypto](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/crypto.html) is the cryptography library.  It has encryption algorithms, key and certificate generation and verification functions, message authentication algorithms, and so on.

Comment: @Charlie: Thanks for the help. Looks like lcrpyto is the library i should be linking it to. 
Thanks a ton!! :) I am seriously worried that there are no proper documentation for this openssl.
But what is -lssl used for?

Comment: @Maverickgugu:  I've updated my answer to describe what `libssl` and `libcrypto` each implement, with links to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to suspect the library isn't being linked correctly.  There are two possibilities:

- the library isn't being linked at all
- the library being linked doesn't include that symbol, suggesting a version mismatch.

The second one seems more probable, but the first is easier to check.  A `man -k ssl` should point out the library man pages.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably in your case "Undefined Symbols" means that you are not linking the correct library.